# Labeling x,y,z coordinates in ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I am VERY new to Mathematica, and am having some difficulty with visualization.  I have a series of points in 3 dimensions (x,y,z) being read from an Excel file.  I can visualize the plot fine using `ListPointPlot3D`, and even organize my values into groups.  What I can NOT figure out is how to have the coordinates show up as text over the circles representing the 3d coordinates.  Here is my code:

```
O1RC = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {3,4,5},{2,3,4}}]
O1BO = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {3,4,5},{5,6,7}}]
CB1RC = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {7,8,9},{2,3,4}}]
CB1BO = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {7,8,9},{5,6,7}}]
CB2RC = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {11,12,13},{2,3,4}}]
CB2BO = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {11,12,13},{5,6,7}}]
IS1RC = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {15,16,17},{2,3,4}}]
IS2RC = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {19,20,21},{2,3,4}}]
MT1RC = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {23,24,25},{2,3,4}}]
DCB1RC = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {27,28,29},{2,3,4}}]
DTB1RC = Import["/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/James/Desktop/EmFiles/2016_3DPlot_Base.xlsx", {"Data", 1, {31,32,33},{2,3,4}}]

ListPointPlot3D[{O1RC,O1BO,CB1RC,CB1BO,CB2RC,CB2BO,IS1RC,IS2RC,MT1RC,DCB1RC,DTB1RC}, AxesLabel -> {"Hue Score Change", "Value Score Change", "Chroma Score Change"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "H2O2 Changes to Sample Colour",
    Background -> White,
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[LightRed, PointSize[0.04], Opacity[0.8]],
                Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]],
                Directive[LightGreen, PointSize[0.04], Opacity[0.8]],
                Directive[Green, PointSize[0.02]],
                Directive[LightBlue, PointSize[0.04], Opacity[0.8]],
                Directive[Blue, PointSize[0.02]],
                Directive[LightCyan, PointSize[0.04], Opacity[0.8]],
                Directive[LightGray, PointSize[0.04], Opacity[0.8]],
                Directive[LightMagenta, PointSize[0.04], Opacity[0.8]],
                Directive[LightYellow, PointSize[0.04], Opacity[0.8]],
                Directive[LightBrown, PointSize[0.04], Opacity[0.8]]},
    PlotLegends -> {"O1RC", "O1BO", "CB1RC", "CB1BO", "CB2RC", "CB2BO", "IS1RC", "IS2RC", "MT1RC", "DCB1RC", "DTB1RC"},
    PlotTheme -> "Marketing",
    Filling -> Bottom];
```

All I want is for the 3 coordinates (x,y,z values) for each of the points generated above to display on the 3d plot.  I've looked at `Tooltip`, `Text`, and `Labeled`, but am having difficulty figuring out how to use any of those to get what I want.  Do I need to use `Graphics3D` instead of a themed `ListPointPlot3D`, and then play around with the Show command to display the coordinate labels?  Help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of one way of putting a text label showing the coordinates centered above each of your points.

```
O1RC={1,1,1}; O1BO={1,2,5}; CB1RC={2,4,7}; CB1BO={3,8,9}; CB2RC={4,10,12};
Show[
  ListPointPlot3D[{O1RC, O1BO, CB1RC, CB1BO, CB2RC}],
  Graphics3D[Map[Text[ToString[#],#,{0,-1}]&, {O1RC,O1BO,CB1RC,CB1BO,CB2RC}]]
]
```

which displays

[image]

For your problem you would use Import to assign values to each variable and use the complete list of your points. And then you desktop publish that image. Remember there are at least half a dozen different ways of doing almost anything in Mathematica. One that you can remember and have it work for you on the first try is often the best one for you.