# Showing the coordinate above the points on graph

Tags: plotting

I am using this code to find convex Hull 
I need to show the coordinates above the points like this example:
[Labeling x,y,z coordinates in ListPointPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107361/labeling-x-y-z-coordinates-in-listpointplot3d)

my code is:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

M = x y z + x^4 + x^2 z^2 + z^4 + y^4

p = CoefficientRules[M][[All, 1]]

{{4, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 4}}

chull = ConvexHullMesh[p];
Show[HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[1, "Index"]], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[p, 0.05]}], Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Text` with `Graphics3D`

```
Show[HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[1, "Index"]], 
     Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[p, 0.05], Blue, 
     Map[Text[#, # + {0., 0, 0.1}] &, p]}]
  , Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]